# About stdout redirect and recover

Tags: c++, c

I want redirect stdout to /dev/null and then recover it for redirect it to stdout.txt, I wrote the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{  

        fprintf(stderr, "stdout before: %d\n", stdout->_fileno);

        freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
        printf("sdfsdf\n");
        freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
        printf("11111\n");

        fprintf(stderr, "stdout end: %d\n", stdout->_fileno);

        return 0;
}
```

Build and test:

```
gcc 1.c -o 1
./1 > stdout.txt
```

why output is:

```
stdout before: 1
11111
stdout end: 1
```

and `stdout.txt` is 0k.

I wish the result is output

```
stdout before: 1
stdout end: 1
```

and the content of `stdout.txt` is 11111

Comment: The program behaves OK on my machine, using gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: OT: Also you'd better use `fileno(stdout)` instead of accessing a `FILE`'s internal member directly.

Comment: You could check the return value of freopen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the output you git are consistent.  The string "11111" goes to the tty because of the freopen line directly before it which changes freopen to point at the tty.

Try using the `dup` system call to save stdout and restore stdout to what it was previously.